# Round table pairs combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics

I know this question will sound easy, but i just cant figure this out. Please help me.

How many ways are there for putting 4 pairs to the round table, so that atleast 1 pair is sitting next to each other.

Comment: How many ways can you pick a pair? How many ways can that pair be seated so that they are next to each other? Then how many ways can you seat everyone else?

Comment: My 'solution' is this: i take 1 pair aside so i will always have atleast 1 pair next to each other, now for 3 pairs its 5! and now i dont know how to include that 1 pair to this.. my result is 5! + 6*2, because there are 6 places where to put that pair and *2 because they can sit like man-woman and woman-man

Comment: The fact that they are seated at a round table suggests to me that two seatings are equivalent if they are the same "up to rotation".

Comment: One approach is to subtract the number of arrangements in which no pair is sitting next to each other from the total number of arrangements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A standard way is to use inclusion-exclusion principle. You count all the possible ways for a certain pair sitting next to each other, then you subtract the overcount and keep doing that until you get the correct count.

Denote the four pairs as $1,2,3,4$. For non-empty $S \subseteq [4]=\{1,2,3,4\}$, 
denote $A_S$ as number of ways to put four pairs on a round table 
such that pairs $i\in S$ sitting next to each other.

To count $A_S$, we can see this $|S|$ pairs
as $|S|$ members in the table, plus $8-2|S|$ non-pair members, which gives
total of $8-|S|$ members on a table so there are $(7-|S|)!$ ways to 
arrange that. We also need to permute members within each pair so there
are $2^{|S|}$ ways to do that. This gives 
$A_S= (7-|S|)! \cdot 2^{|S|}$.

Now, to use inclusion-exclusion principle, we have the final answer
as
\begin{align*}
\sum_{S\subseteq A,|S| \ge 1}(-1)^{|S|+1}A_S & =
\sum_{S\subseteq A, |S| \ge 1}(-1)^{|S|+1}
(7-|S|)! \cdot 2^{|S|}, \\
& = \binom{4}{1} (-1)^2 \cdot 6! \cdot 2 + \binom{4}{2}(-1)^3 \cdot 5! \cdot 2^2 \\
&+\binom{4}{3}(-1)^4\cdot 4!\cdot 2^3+\binom{4}{4}(-1)^5\cdot 3!\cdot 2^4.
\end{align*}